# Trouble With jquery.matchHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to match the height of the content area and sidebar on the following site:

- http://www.dev-cheweng.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/about/

I've added the following line of code to my file js.js

```
$('.height-page').matchHeight();
```

Here is the class for my content area:

```
<div id="content" class="grid_8 height-page">
```

And my sidebar:

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="grid_4">
    <div class="content height-page">
```

The script appear to be loading fine, just they're not matching the height. All I get output for both elements is along these lines:

```
<div class="grid_8 height-page" id="content" style="">
```

I did originally target each element in the Js with their individual IDs / classes, but couldn't get that to work either. So then I thought maybe I can only apply the height matching to specific classes, hence me going with .height-page , but of course that doesn't work either

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> ```
> $(function() {
>     $('.item').matchHeight();
> });
> ```
>
> Will set all elements with the class item to the height of the
>   tallest.

That means that you have to give your sidebar and your content area the same class (at the moment they don't have a common class)

Here's [a demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/jquery.matchHeight.html) of it working as expected.

Comment: thanks that seems to do the trick! Wow I'm confused though, I would have thought I'd only need to select the `.content` within `#sidebar`... but looks like I was wrong!